# Django translations and gettext: The deprecation of the % (string interpolation) operator

Tags: django, string, internationalization, deprecated, string-interpolation

Although Django Django does not yet support Python 3, it eventually will, so I want to keep my code the more "future-proof" possible.

Since Python 2.7 the string interpolation operator (`%`) is being deprecated. And I realized that every string that needs to be translated is using the `%` interpolation syntax. And in the Django docs there is no mention of the new `str.format` method (the "new" official way of string formatting)...

Maybe there is a limitation of the `gettext` library, but I don't think so, since the string appears identical in the .PO files.

The question is if I can use the new string `format` method for translation.

The old way:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return _('%(title)s (%(date)s)') % {
            'title': self.title,
            'date': self.date,
        }
```

The "new" way:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return _('{title} ({date})').format(
            title=self.title,
            date=self.date,
        )
```

Also, `ugettext_lazy` does not really return strings, but `Promises`, objects that are evaluated only when needed.

Comment: Have you tried? You don't make it clear whether you've tried and failed or are just generally asking if it's possible. I don't see any obvious reason it *shouldn't* work, but if it does fail, then Django gettext extensions must just simply be incompatible, which means you're essentially out of luck. When Django supports Python 3, you'll be able to use it like Python 3.

Comment: I have tried and everything seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if it is the "right" way of doing this, since the docs doesn't mention anything about this deprecation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use it safely. For example

```
ugettext_lazy('{foo}').format(foo='bar')
```

The translation program `xgettext`, which is used by Django, does not care about the content to be translated. It just searches `.py` file for keywords such as `ugettext_lazy` or `_` to collect the translatable strings(refs [the manual of xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) and [Django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L191))

Furthermore, the `.format()` method above is a wrapper provided by the proxy object, like:

```
>>> ugettext_lazy(u'{foo}').format
<bound method __proxy__.__wrapper__ of <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x102f19050>>
```

The invoking of the above `.format()` would get `u'{foo}'` to be translated to some unicode `value`, then call `value.format` with actual arguments. You could see that the translation and `value.format` happen in different stages.

Comment: Could you elucidate on what happens with the new fstrings?

Comment: @AdamBarnes There is no magic. f-strings are formatted by Python. If you use f-strings inside `_()`, the `_` function will receive an already formatted string (with `{foo}` already replaced) and will not found the right reference string in the translation table (`.mo` files).