# Strings won't be translated in Django using format function available in Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, translation

Does the new and recommended way to format strings available in Python 2.7 using `format` result in a non translated string in Django?

The strings are in the `.po` file, translated, but it won't be translated on the website. For example:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

website_name = "Stackoverflow"
title = _(u"{sitename} is a good website".format(sitename=website_name))
```

The `.po` file after translating the string looks like this:

```
#: path/to/file.py:4
msgid "{sitename} is a good website"
msgstr "{sitename} ist eine gute Website"
```

After running `django-admin.py compilemessages` and restarting the webserver, on the processed HTML page it is still in english, while all the other strings are being translated. Furthermore, while all strings using `format` are not translated, strings formatted using the `%` operator are translated as expected. It is also not a gettext/ugettext issue, as the problem is the same with both functions.

Comment: have you tried `_(u"{sitename} is a good website").format...`

Comment: This solved the problem. I was searching for hours for a solution before asking here, so thanks a lot for your quick and helpful reply. Why did you post it as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: Doesn't apply to OP, but note about `format`: `Python’s str.format() method will not work when either the format_string or any of the arguments to str.format() contains lazy translation objects.` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#formatting-strings-format-lazy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`compilemessages` sees the string as "{sitename} is a good website", but when the app is running the string is actually e.g. "MySite is a good website", which of course doesn't have a translation. You must translate the bare string first, and *then* you can perform template operations on it.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, this would mean `_(u"{sitename} is a good website").format(sitename=website_name)` (note the different position of the parenthesis). This also works fine with `ugettext_lazy`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999954/django-translations-and-gettext-the-deprecation-of-the-string-interpolation

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
_('Foo %(x)s') % {'x': "bar"}
```

`s` is the string, `d` is the intiger.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem so i translated the text first and then added the dynamic content like

```
title = _(u"is a good website")
title = " ".join([website_name, title])
```

There must be a better way to do this

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the dynamic part (placeholder) must be part of the string to allow a language specific placement within the phrase. In your solution it would be fix at the beginning of the string.