# django translation with format() does not work

Tags: django

django translation does not happen for a field using choices..

models.py:

```
 class Reservation(models.Model):
  class Period:
    MORNING = 'morning'
    EVENING = 'evening'

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return (                
            (cls.MORNING, _('Morning')),
            (cls.EVENING, '{} until {:%I %p}'.format(_('Evening'), datetime.time(16)),
        )       

 period = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Period.choices(),)
```

I am using {{ reservation.get_period_display }} in the template to display the field in few languages.Translation is fine for first choice cls.MORNING: الصباح. 
For the second choice (cls.EVENING), translation does not happen:"Evening until 04 PM"

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong with the format specifier, and why translation/localization is not working in this case.

*N.B: The translation and i18n is setup properly and other places in my project is correctly showing translated values*.

Comment: What is `_`? Is it `ugettext_lazy` or the non-lazy version?

Comment: _ is ugettext_lazy version

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap second line string in `ugettex_lazy` not just `Evening`

```
(cls.EVENING, _('{} until {:%I %p}').format(datetime.time(16)),
```

Read more [Strings won't be translated in Django using format function available in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602536/strings-wont-be-translated-in-django-using-format-function-available-in-python)

Also be sure to add `#, python-brace-format`. Like in this example

```
#: accounts/forms.py:691
#, python-brace-format
msgid "La validation de votre carte a échoué: ({0}) {1}"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: "{} until {:%I %p}" appears in django.po file. translation does not work irrespective of whatever string you provide for this.

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel see updated answer. I fixed first line too using `_().format`

Comment: added po file:
#, python-brace-format
msgid "until {}"
msgstr "حتى {}"

still not getting translation..,

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel try with indexes.

Comment: thanks for asking. unfortunately the problem still exists. BTW can you give an example for using indexes.i want to use dates in my case '{} ({:%I:%M %p} - {:%I:%M %p})',

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel Try this `{0} ({1:%I:%M %p} - {2:%I:%M %p})`

Comment: if you consider this :_('{0}').format( 'Morning'), the value Morning is supplied at (if i can use) runtime. In the po file  well it'll be:    #, python-brace-format
    msgid "{0}"
    msgstr "{0}"  there should be another way to get out of this wierd stuff

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel So is it working or not? Also you need to translate morning separtely. Don't forget that your code is parsed by a script and it may not know how to handle your case, sometimes you need to do things manually.

Comment: No its not working., _('{0}').format(_('Morning')) in this case, i am trying to use plain text alone.,why it would not work? thanks

Comment: @GrizzledSquirrel It should be just "Moring" `_('{0}').format('Morning') `. Why you are wrapping it in ugettext?

Comment: somehow this is working fine except that date format is not coming as translated  [code]  _(u'{period} ({start_date:%I:%M %p}').format(period=_('Morning'), start_date=mydatetimefunction()) [code]